# Hyperbola parametrics

Tags: calculus

I have the following problem.

A particle moves on the top part of hyperbola  $$y^2 - x^2 = 9$$ in such a way that the horizontal component of the velocity vector is $3$.

Determine vectors velocity and acceleration when $t = 2$ and the particle is at point $P(4,5)$.

First try:

$$\vec{r} (t)= (3 \tan(t), 3 \sec(t))$$

$$\vec{v} (t) = (3 \sec^2(t), 3 \sec(t) \tan(t))$$

$$\vec{a} (t) = (6 \sin(t) / \cos^3(t), 3 (\sin(t) + 1) / \cos^3(t))$$

Second try:

$$\vec{r} (t) = ( t , \sqrt{9+t^2})$$

$$\vec{v} (t) = ( 1 , t / \sqrt{9+t^2} )$$

$$\vec{a} (t) = ( 0 ,  9 / (9+t^2)\sqrt{9+t^2} )$$

Is there something wrong with what I am doing? The problem says the horizontal component of the velocity vector is $3$, but I get different results, and I am not sure what to do with $P(4,5)$.

Any tips on how to solve that problem?

Please excuse my english. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. For the English language you are excused because i have difficulty too but for mathjax no ahahahah. I am joking. +1 for the question.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano , you are right, for the next question I will pay more attention to it.

Comment: I am joking, hope you are not offended. A big hello and I hope you come back to MSE soon.

Comment: I am not offended, it does look way better like this, I can learn from your edits, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As horizontal component of velocity is $3$, $x = 3t + c$

When $t = 2$, particle is at $P(4,5) $ i.e $x = 4$

So, $4 = 3 \cdot 2 + c \implies c = -2$

Now $y^2-x^2 = 9 \implies y^2 = 9 + (3t-2)^2 = 9t^2 - 12t + 13$

As $y \geq 0, r(t) = (3t-2, \sqrt{9t^2-12t+13})$

Now you can differentiate and find $v(t)$ and $a(t)$ vectors at $t=2$.

Comment: Thank you very much.